# Crop a texture down to a smaller texture using slick and lwjgl (JAVA)

Tags: java, lwjgl, crop, slick2d

Below I have written a method to draw a texture that is given in it's parameters.

```
    public void drawImage(Texture texture, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    texture.bind();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(width, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(width, height);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, height);
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

I don't want to change THIS method. Instead, what I would like to do is create a method that crops a sprite sheet ranging in any size and having any number of crops that I might need to be saved as separate textures.

Previously, I was using Java.AWT which allowed for me to do exactly this. See code below. Note: sheet is of type BufferedImage.

```
public BufferedImage crop(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    return sheet.getSubimage(x*width, y*height, width, height);
}
```

I'm trying to find equivalent code for the above method that can take one texture in of any size, crop any area out and return that area as its own texture.

I am not trying to change the drawImage method as I need that method exactly the way it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out there is a built in function in slick called BufferedImageUtil that converts buffered images into texture. This is a simple answer rather than to try to make something that gets subImage like in BufferedImage, the smarter approach is to convert a BufferedImage into a texture which I have been trying to do for about 3 months now.

For anyone struggling with this kind of conversion, simply use code like I have below.

```
    SpriteSheet Tiles = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("/res/Tiles.png"));
    BufferedImage test = Tiles.crop(0, 0, 64, 64);
    Texture test2 = null;
    try {
        test2 = BufferedImageUtil.getTexture("", test);                             
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g.drawImage(test2, 0, 0, 64, 64);
```

SpriteSheet class:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
/**
 * This Class is responsible for splitting up sprite sheets into multiple images.
 * @author Kenneth
 *
 */
public class SpriteSheet {

private BufferedImage sheet;
/**
 * This constructor receives the image that needs to be modified.
 * @param sheet
 */
public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage sheet){
    this.sheet = sheet;
}
/**
 * This crops a sprite sheet to get the subimage within the picture.
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param width
 * @param height
 * @return
 */
public BufferedImage crop(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    return sheet.getSubimage(x*width, y*height, width, height);
}
}
```

ImageLoader:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
/**
 * This class is responsible for loading in images
 * @author Kenneth
 *
 */
public class ImageLoader {
/**
 * This method tries to load in the selected image from the path given.
 * @param path
 * @return
 */
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path)); //Loads in image
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1); //If the image cannot be loaded, the window closes
        System.err.println(path + " was not loaded.");
    }
    return null;
}

}
```